# Is there a possibility to make the icon in preferences grey when preference is disabled?

Tags: java, android, icons, androidx, preferences

I have a preference screen with a SwitchPreferenceCompat which is the dependency for other preferences. All preferences have icons. Now when switching the SwitchPreferenceCompat on and off, the preferences got enabled and disabled but the icon still is white (in dark theme) or dark gray (in Light Theme).

How can I make the icon become the same color as the text if the preference is disabled? Is there a way to make it in the xml or in the styles.xml or do I have to make it programmatic in my PinSettingsPreferenceFragment?

Here my preference.xml:

```
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory

        android:title="Pin Settings">

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="pref_key_password_secure"
            android:title="@string/activate_pin_mode"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:icon="?attr/ic_secure"
            android:summary="@string/set_pin_activity_label"/>

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_key_pin"
            android:title="@string/pin"
            android:summary="@string/please_enter_pin"
            android:dependency="pref_key_password_secure"
            android:icon="?attr/ic_password"/>

        <PreferenceCategory

            android:title="Fingerprint Settings"
            android:dependency="pref_key_password_secure">

            <SwitchPreferenceCompat
                android:key="pref_key_fingerprint_secure"
                android:title="@string/activate_fingerprint_mode_if_available"
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:icon="?attr/ic_finger_print"
                android:summary="@string/use_fingerprint_for_secure_summary"/>

        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Thanks for Help